# How can I extract an object in threejs format using blender

Tags: three.js, blender

I want to convert my object to THIS particular format

```
{

    "metadata" :
    {
        "formatVersion" : 3.1,
        "generatedBy"   : "Blender 2.7 Exporter",
        "vertices"      : 8,
        "faces"         : 6,
        "normals"       : 8,
        "colors"        : 0,
        "uvs"           : [4],
        "materials"     : 1,
        "morphTargets"  : 0,
        "bones"         : 0
    },

    "scale" : 1.000000,

    "materials" : [ {
        "DbgColor" : 15658734,
        "DbgIndex" : 0,
        "DbgName" : "bake_mat.013",
        "blending" : "NormalBlending",
        "colorAmbient" : [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
        "colorDiffuse" : [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
        "colorEmissive" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
        "depthTest" : true,
        "depthWrite" : true,
        "mapDiffuse" : "b_cb-blue-block60x96.png",
        "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
        "shading" : "Lambert",
        "specularCoef" : 50,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "transparent" : false,
        "vertexColors" : false
    }],

    "vertices" : [-76.2,-0.249995,121.92,-76.2,-0.250005,-121.92,76.2,-0.250005,-121.92,76.2,-0.249995,121.92,-76.2,0.250005,121.92,-76.2,0.249995,-121.92,76.2,0.249995,-121.92,76.2,0.250005,121.92],

    "morphTargets" : [],

    "normals" : [-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349],

    "colors" : [],

    "uvs" : [[-2e-06,0.999998,2e-06,-2e-06,1,2e-06,0.999998,1]],

    "faces" : [43,1,0,4,5,0,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,43,5,6,2,1,0,2,3,0,1,3,4,5,0,43,6,7,3,2,0,2,3,0,1,4,6,7,5,43,0,3,7,4,0,0,1,2,3,1,7,6,2,43,0,1,2,3,0,2,3,0,1,1,0,5,7,43,7,6,5,4,0,2,3,0,1,6,4,3,2],

    "bones" : [],

    "skinIndices" : [],

    "skinWeights" : [],

  "animations" : []


}
```

I tried using blender, but I doesn't gives me these particular keys and nodes that I desire. Does anyone know how this can be achieved? When I try to export the models, I get js like cars.js but I want it to be like the other js.

Please see the attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use the exporter from Blender to Three.js? It's in the distributive of Three.js and you can find it there at [`utils/exporters/blender`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender). Instruction of how to integrate it into Blender is included.

Comment: @prisoner849, yes I tried that as well. But the js that I was receiving when I export it. it is not exactly that I need. Both have different structures

Comment: @prisoner849 Please check my edited question. I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: What format do you need? If you require a custom format, you are going to have to create your own exporter or converter